# A scanning tool

Tags: scanning

I am new to programming. I want to develop a tool which allows scanning the date of multiple products. For example, by this tool, I want to check if products on a shelf (let's say 25/30 products) are expiring on a specific date. The purpose of developing this tool is to eliminate the need for manually looking at the date of every single product. So my question is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to convert an image into a date for products using a camera, or use an OCR tool.

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-5-free-ocr-software-tools-to-convert-your-images-into-text-nb/